# Will a unit disk be completely covered by randomly placed disks of area $\pi,\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{3},\dots$ with probability $1$?

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, sequences-and-series, geometric-probability

On a "bottom" disk of area $\pi$, we place "top" disks of area $\pi,\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{3},\dots$ such that the centre of each top disk is an independent uniformly random point on the bottom disk.

> Will the bottom disk be completely covered by the top disks with probability $1$?

We have a strong [argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4810544/398708) that if the bottom disk's area is less than $\pi$ then the probability that it will be covered is $1$, and if the bottom disk's area is greater than $\pi$ then the probability that it will be covered is less than $1$. But the boundary case seems to be more difficult.

Comment: A charming question! :)

Comment: There is a similar question for the unit circumference and covering by random arcs that was fully answered (see Kahane's "Some random series of functions", Chapter 11). Have you tried the techniques from there?

Comment: More generally, this is called "Dvoretzky problem". It looks like the 1D case (covering interval with smaller intervals) is completely solved, and if you believe the 2D case is the same then the answer to this question should be "yes". However, I couldn't find a reference for the 2D case.

Comment: Unfortunately, some of the reference books on this topic are behind paywalls, so I couldn't study them...

Comment: @fedja I haven't seen that book.

Comment: @fedja I have laid my hand on Kahane's book. In particular, it contains a much better proof of the case $A > 1$. Thanks for the reference!

Comment: Let a sequence $(r_n)_{n\ge1}$ be given. Let  a sequence of points 
$u,x_1,x_2,\dots$ 
be chosen independently and uniformly at random within a given open set  $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^2$ of area $a$. Then, I'd say the probability that $u\notin\bigcup_{n\ge1}B(x_n,r_n)$, that is, that for all $n\ge1$ one has $|u-x_n|\ge r_n$ is $$\frac1{|\Omega|}\int_{\Omega}\prod_{n\ge1} \frac{|\Omega\setminus B(u,r_n)|}{|\Omega|} du.$$

Comment: For any $u\in\Omega$, one has eventually $B(u,r_n)\subset \Omega$ , so  the ratio of areas in the infinite product is eventually  $1-\frac{B_n(u,r_n)}{|\Omega|}$, which in the present case is $1-\frac{\pi}{na}$, and this make it vanish identically. So I should get the paradoxical conclusion that $\Omega\setminus\bigcup_{n\ge1}B_n$ has zero measure with probability  $1$, even for large bottom disk. Or is this argument incorrect?

Comment: Your argument is correct, but there are plenty of nonempty sets with zero measure e.g. Cantor sets.

Comment: Yes, so from “covering a.e.” to “complete covering” there is quite a difference, which seems counterintuitive to me

Comment: Based on the "strong argument", it could only make sense to expect probability 1 for the boundary case by a continuity argument.

Comment: Funnily, the answer is going to be the same with top disks of areas $\frac{\pi}{100}, \frac{\pi}{101}, \frac{\pi}{102}, \dots$